# Null in LINQ To SQL

Tags: c#, linq, null

Why following two linq statements are different?

```
var CurrencyId = (await currencies.Where(a => a.CurrencyCode == "non existing code")).Select(b => b.CurrencyId).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

var CurrencyId = (byte)(await currencies.FirstOrDefaultAsync(a => a.CurrencyCode == "non existing code"))?.CurrencyId;
```

The first statement executes fine without any error, with CurrencyId = 0, while the second throws an exception;

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value.
```

Can someone please explain?

Comment: See that `(byte)` cast? That requires something that's not `null`, whether you use `?.` or not. The first one gives you `default(byte)`, which is `0`.

Comment: Okay how about this one then? (Removed the casting but still throwing NullReferenceException; CurrencyId = (await currencies.FirstOrDefaultAsync(a => a.CurrencyCode == "non existing code")).CurrencyId;

Comment: I had to do the cast as 'CurrencyId' is not null in my code/model.

Comment: Of course, because now you are asking for the `CurrencyId` member of a `null` reference. What are you really after, here? What *do* you want as the result if there's no value? `0`? Then use `?.CurrencyId ?? 0`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Yes, that's what I really wanted and what you suggested worked. So many thanks. My question still remains that why first linq statement works fine, leaving CurrencyId = 0, while the second throws a nullreferenceexception.

Comment: Look at the types the methods are returning. In the first case, you do a `.Select(b => b.CurrencyId)`, which returns `IEnumerable<byte>`. You then do `.FirstOrDefault()` on that, which returns a `byte`, since the enumerable is empty. In the second case, you do `FirstOrDefaultAsync()` directly on `currencies`, which will return `null`, since that's the "default value" of a `Currency` that doesn't exist. In the first case, you never see a `null`, which is why things work the way they do. Operations on an empty enumerable are legal, operations on `null` are not.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Which linq query is better to use in my code? I mean which one is better in performance and readability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we evaluate the first line of code, one step at a time:

```
(await currencies.Where(a => a.CurrencyCode == "non existing code")).Select(b => b.CurrencyId).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

EmptyEnumerable<Currency>.Select(b => b.CurrencyId).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

EmptyEnumerable<int>.FirstOrDefaultAsync();

0;
```

And the second version:

```
(byte)(await currencies.FirstOrDefaultAsync(a => a.CurrencyCode == "non existing code"))?.CurrencyId;

(byte)null?.CurrencyId;

(byte)null;

// BANG
```

Comment: Cheer Buh Buh for nice explanation :)

Comment: Which linq query is better to use in my code? I mean which one is better in performance and readability?

Comment: I would use the first because it is simpler to do all the work in linq, rather than linq+dot operator+casting. Furthermore it does not through an exception, which is presumably why you were using the `*OrDefault` functions in the first place.